# Math function for hours in a month

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, math, momentjs

Is there a Math function to calculate hours in a month excluding weekends?

Lets say I get the days in a month with `MomentJS`. A working day has 7:36 Hours and there are 5 days in a week that you have to work(excluding weekends).

If for example the month has **30 days** and I know that there is **7:36 hours per day (7Hours and 36Minutes)** but I need to **exclude every weekend** in the month how would a function like this look like / is it even possible to have a function like this? I need it to work in React Native so JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting working days

```js
const pad = num => ("0" + num).slice(-2);
const minutesPerDay = 7 * 60 + 36; // or 7.6 hours
const isWorkingDay = d => d.getDay() !== 0 && d.getDay() !== 6;
const getHHMM = m => `${Math.floor(m / 60)}:${pad(m % 60)}`;

const getHours = (year, month) => {
  const startDate = new Date(year, month - 1, 1, 15, 0, 0); // we need a date object
  const endDay = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate(); // and number of days in the month
  console.log("start", new Date(startDate), "end", "+" + endDay)

  let workingDays = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= endDay; i++) { // count from 1 to and including last day of month
    startDate.setDate(i); // reuse startdate object
    workingDays += isWorkingDay(startDate) ? 1 : 0; // if 0 or 6, ignore
  }
  return getHHMM(workingDays * minutesPerDay); // format to HH:MM
};
console.log(getHours(2020, 1)); // jan
console.log(getHours(2020, 2)); // feb
```

Comment: In Feb 2020 there are 20 working days Feb starts with an Saturday so the result for Feb should be 152Hours but your function is giving 147.20 - Thanks anyways!

Comment: Doesnt give me the right values for the months also it doenst round well because there are values like 172.80 what cant be because a min has 60 max

Comment: `let i = startDate; i <= endDate; i += aDay` this could fail when summer time starts - better off using `x.setDate(x.getDate() + 1)`

Comment: @JaromandaX I actually had taken care of that using 15:00 for time. But of course you are correct. I have simplified the script

Comment: using the time 15:00 wouldn't do jack, since adding 24 hours would make the time 16:00 after summer time starts for every day - and since you compare with 15:00 ... you could use start time of 12:00 and end time of 13:00 ... but the code you have now is probably better

Comment: I still have to do 15 or I will get a start date as December 31 in my timezone (Jan st at midnight) - I did not compare minutes, only day number so 15 or 16 is irrelevant

Comment: This function actually seems to work for me now is it possible to just get the hours as a value not the whole date object ? like 152 for feburary

Comment: @yesIamFaded Inpired by functional programming I refactored a bit

Answer (score 0):

I defined an iterator for the days of the month, plus a predicate to check which are not week ends.

**Notes**

- Month number starts at 0. So January = 0. I have made the iterator take the month number offset by one, making January = 1.
- Days of the week too. So Sunday = 0 and Saturday = 6.

```js
function isNotWeekEnd(date)
{
    let dayOfTheWeek = date.getDay();
    return dayOfTheWeek != 0 && dayOfTheWeek != 6;
}

function* daysOfTheMonth(year, month)
{
    let monthEnd = new Date(year, month, 1);
    let dayOfTheMonth = 1;
    let dayStart = new Date(year, month - 1, dayOfTheMonth);
    while(monthEnd - dayStart > 0)
    {
        yield dayStart;
        dayOfTheMonth++;
        dayStart = new Date(year, month - 1, dayOfTheMonth);
    }
}

const workHoursPerDay = 7.6; // 7 hours plus 36 minutes
let nonWeekEnds = Array.from(daysOfTheMonth(2020, 1 /* January*/)).filter(isNotWeekEnd);
let workHours = nonWeekEnds.length * workHoursPerDay;

console.log({workHours});
```

Output:

```
{
    "workHours": 174.79999999999998
}
```

I should be able to avoid the date objects by merging the predicate in the iterator. In fact, I do not need an iterator, just the number of days.

```js
const millisecondsPerSecond = 1000;
const secondsPerHour = 3600;
const hoursPerDay = 24;

const workHoursPerDay = 7.6; // 7 hours plus 36 minutes

const millisecondsPerDay = millisecondsPerSecond * secondsPerHour * hoursPerDay;

function daysInMonth(year, month)
{
    let monthEnd = new Date(year, month, 1);
    let monthStart = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
    let millisecondsInMonth = monthEnd - monthStart;
    return millisecondsInMonth / millisecondsPerDay;
}

function notWeekEndsOfTheMonth(year, month)
{
    const daysPerWeek = 7;
    let daysOfTheMonth = daysInMonth(year, month);
    let dayOfTheMonth = 1;
    let dayStart = new Date(year, month - 1, dayOfTheMonth);
    let dayOfTheWeek = dayStart.getDay();
    let days = 0;
    while(daysOfTheMonth >= dayOfTheMonth)
    {
        if (dayOfTheWeek != 0 && dayOfTheWeek != 6)
        {
            days++;
        }
        dayOfTheMonth++;
        dayOfTheWeek = (dayOfTheWeek + 1) % daysPerWeek;
    }
    return days;
}

let workHours = notWeekEndsOfTheMonth(2020, 1 /* January */) * workHoursPerDay;

console.log({workHours});
```

Comment: I get 174:48 in Jan

Comment: @mplungjan I'm aware, I'm currently trying to understand your code.

Comment: Your while is far too complicated. Just add a day to the date and do a getDay()

Comment: @mplungjan well, your code mixes presentation and computation concerns and has too many magic numbers.

Comment: I believe I have gotten rid of many of those concerns and the ONLY magic number was given by OP. 7:36. No other magic numbers at all. Also I was not criticising you in any unfriendly manner - no need to be defensive

Comment: @mplungjan Ah, thank you. That fixes why I got a different result. *I think I understand something different than you by "magic number".*

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to translate the click function to react, but the functions could work for you :)

You need to know the month and also the year :). I use the date selector to make it easy to select the month and try. But the important data is in the month and in the year.

```js
function getDaysMonth(m, y) {
   return 32 - new Date(y, m, 32).getDate();
}

function checkWorkingDay(y, m, d) {
    let day = new Date(y, m, d).getDay();
    return day !=0 && day !=6;
}

function getHoursInMonth(month, year) {
   let days = getDaysMonth(month, year);
   let weekdays = 0;
   for(var i=0; i< days; i++) {
       if (checkWorkingDay(year, month, i+1)) weekdays++;
   }
   
   let minutes = (weekdays * ((7 * 60) + 36));

   return Math.floor(minutes / 60) + ':' + (minutes % 60);
}

  
document.getElementById("dateInput").addEventListener("change", function() {
    let input = this.value;
    let myDate = new Date(input);
    let hours = getHoursInMonth(myDate.getMonth(), myDate.getYear()); 
    document.getElementById("dateOutput").innerHTML = hours;
});
```

```html
<input type="date" id="dateInput" />
<p id="dateOutput"></p>
```